# How to center text center using grid-template-columns

Tags: css

I need to center the text of these 3 div from each box, I tried to use `justify-content: center` and`text-align: center` didn't work, how could I center these texts?

```css
 div {width: 100%}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(155px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px 10px
}

.grid a>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 290px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative
}

.grid a>div .info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30px;
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.grid a>div .info>strong {
  height: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  /*justify-content: center;
       text-align: center*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a href="">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="info absolute">
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div><!--grid-->
```

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gsRt.png)

Comment: absolute positionned element do not see nor care about the size of their parents, you need to add width:100%; to fill entire width of the closest positioned parent and eventually reset coordonates. besides it seems like you mix flex and grid or forget to set display grid ... .info : width:100% + display:flex not grid  ,  strong is missing display:grid

Comment: @G-Cyr 
In strong I did not define the size because she wants to be responsive, has any property that fills the div the father respecting the limit of each? (one side is shown as a space between) 
set `div {width: 100%}` just forgot to mention

Comment: strong doesn't require a width, .info is the one in absolute. strong has a grid-template-columns, but no display, ??? .info has flex rules , but a display:grid ... you should clean up a bit your code to avoid getting confused ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `strong` elements to take up 100% of the space available, for that you'd need to set them to `display: block;` and `width: 100%` with your current setup:

```css
 div {width: 100%}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(155px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px 10px
}

.grid a>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 290px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative
}

.grid a>div .info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30px;
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.grid a>div .info>strong {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a href="">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="info absolute">
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
        <strong class="align-items">xxx</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div><!--grid-->
```

BUT block-elements within an inline element (like `<a>`) are invalid markup and I think you could achieve the same result much easier like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(155px, 1fr));
}

.grid .item {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #969696;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 290px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid .info {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}

.grid .info-item {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #111;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span class="content">
      I'm some content
    </span>
    <span class="info">
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span class="content">
      I'm some content
    </span>
    <span class="info">
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span class="content">
      I'm some content
    </span>
    <span class="info">
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
      <strong class="info-item">xxx</strong>
    </span>
  </a>
</div><!--grid-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `text-align:center;` property on the parent tag, like that :

```
.info{
  text-align:center;
}
```